# NavigationView menu item title color

Tags: android, navigationview

Lets say I have a menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="@string/menu_title">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_menu_item_1"
                android:icon="@drawable/nav_menu_item_1"
                android:title="@string/nav_menu_item_1" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

I can easily change color of "nav_menu_item_1" title like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorCustom"
    ... />
```

However this doesn't change color of

```
<item android:title="@string/menu_title">
```

How can I change color of first level menu item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add `android:textColorSecondary` into your style.xml

```
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

it works for me

Ouptput

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Set in Your theme...** `android:actionMenuTextColor`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

**Or By Code**

```
 MenuItem settingsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
 SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsMenuItem.getTitle());
 s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, s.length(), 0);
 settingsMenuItem.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: Hi Arjun I have checked android:actionMenuTextColor but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can change it set **theme** to your NavigationView

Create in style.xml

```
<style name="NavigationView">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/clPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecond</item>
</style>
```

Set **theme** in layout

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/sheetAdd_nv_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationView"
    app:itemTextColor="?attr/clText"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_sheet_add" />
```